# Select from multiple sql-databases using one query

Tags: mysql

Currently I will use two queries to select data from different databases.

Here´s the main sections from the code..

**query from database 1**

```
mysql_select_db("data1");
mysql_select_db("data2");
//bought databases connected
$query1 = "select * from ex.1 where value1='".$value1."' and value2='".$value2."'  order by number ASC;";
$run1 = mysql_query($query1);
```

**query from database 2**

```
$query2= " select * from ex.2 where value1='".$value1."' and value2='".$value2."'  order by number ASC;";
$run2 = mysql_query($query2);
```

Both tables in different databases will include same information from the strings `"$value1"` and `"$value2"`.

I would like to combine these two strings in one query. Meaning that all information from two different databases will be selected.

I tried to use JOIN the following way:

```
$query = "select * from database1.ex.1 JOIN database2.ex.2 where value1='".$value1."' and value2='".$value2."'  order by number ASC;";
$run = mysql_query($query);
```

but no success..
Meaning from all this is that I would like to echo mysql-data to the same table from two different database.

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){   
echo '</tr><td>'.($row['something']).'</td><td>'.($row['more']).'</td><td>'.($row['and more']).'</td><td>'.($row['and more']).'</td><td>'.($row['and something from the database2']);
```

This way all information should be echoed nicely, following the few strings which will found from both databases.

Is this understandable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using mysql_* for your PHP scripts, you should use MySQLI as mysql is being deprecated.

```
$db = new mysqli(host, user, password, database;
```

You should also escape the strings to be more secure and check to see if the connection has been successful as well:

```
$dbhost = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$dbuser = "xxxxxxx";
$dbpass = "xxxxxx";
$dbbase = "xxxxxx";

$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbbase);
if($db->connect_errno) {
    die('Could not connect to the database: ' . $db->connect_error);
}
```

You can follow this and repeat for multiple databases!

Comment: Thanks, that way I managed to connect to multiple databases! Helpful answers from you.

Comment: **I still have one issue left. See the used query:** `$query = "select * from database1.ex.1 as db1 JOIN database2.ex.2 as db2 ON(db1.value1 ='".$value1."' and db1.value2='".$value2."' and db2.value1 ='".$value1."' and db2.value2='".$value2."' and db1.number = db2.number);";` **This query will select only rows where results matches from both databases. I would like have all rows echoed from db1(following the strings) and one value from db2(if exists following the strings)**

Comment: I tried to fix this by using LEFT JOIN but if I want use that option I have to add where clause to the query. Problem is that I have "value2" column at both tables, result for that I receive **"clause is ambiguous 757"** error message. Here´s the latest query:`$query = "select * from database1.ex.1 as db1 LEFT JOIN database2.ex.2 as db2 ON(db1.value1 ='".$value1."' and db1.value2='".$value2."' and db2.value1 ='".$value1."' and db2.value2='".$value2."' and db1.number = db2.number) where value1='".$value1."' and value2='".$value2."';";`

Comment: This is fixed by following update: `where db.1value1='".$value1."' and db1.value2='".$value2."';";` I also remove * from select clause (replaced by column names).

Answer (score 0):

You have the join part right, but you have got the clause where instead of on:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM database1.ex.1 as db1 JOIN database2.ex.2 as db2 
ON(db1.value1='".$value1."' and db2.value2='".$value2."')  order by number ASC;";
```

You can change db1.value1/db1.value2 for db2.whatever.